# How to represent a long sequence of arrays?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to represent an assignment with a long list of variables. How can I make it compact?
I tried generate and net list, but couldn't figure it out. The length may be variable and thus parameter must be used.

```
    assign ldistance = 
          distance(upin[127:120],downin[127:120])
          + .....
          + distance(upin[23:16],downin[23:16])
          + distance(upin[15:8],downin[15:8])
          + distance(upin[7:0],downin[7:0]);
```

Comment: In Verilog generate blocks do not work the same way as in c++ or java - they're used to provide control over the creation of many types of module items.

Comment: Is this for the testbench or RTL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an edit, 'gnoejh' stated he solved this problem in the following way:

```
genvar p;
assign ldist[0] = 0;
generate
for (p=1; p < `CHANNELS + 1; p = p + 1) begin
    assign ldist[p] = (ldist[p-1] + distance(upin[(8 * (p-1)) +: 8], 
                       downin[(8 * (p-1)) +: 8])>>2);
end 
endgenerate

assign ldistance = ldist[`CHANNELS];
```

Answer (score 4):

For IEEE1364-2001 or newer:

```
parameter WIDTH=128;
integer ldistance;
integer lsb;
always @* begin
    ldistance = 0;
    for(lsb=0; lsb<WIDTH; lsb=lsb+8) begin
        ldistance = ldistance + distance( upin[lsb +: 8], downin[lsb +: 8] );
    end
end
```